# Is it possible to combine variables in a jeykll if statement?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to combine both site.url and page.url in a jeykll template if statement, for example (it doesn't work this way though):

```
{% if comment.path == {{ site.url }}{{ page.url}} %}
```

Comment: Have you tried `{% if comment.path == site.url + page.url %}`?

Comment: I've tried "&&", "&" and "+". None of them seemed to work though, without the brackets, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
{% capture fullpath %}{{ site.url }}{{ page.url}}{% endcapture %}
{% if comment.path == fullpath %}
```

Comment: Hey, it worked. Thanks a lot. It didn't cross my mind to use the capture tag.